# curious about other people's html document structure

Tags: html

There are so many different ways to structure html documents and I was just wondering how people go about it. For example I've seen websites recommend about 4 slightly different ways to include the css file (media, type, version etc).

I was just wondering if there was actually a definitive way of doing it.
After a bit of research I have started using the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0" media="all">
    <script src="js/script.js?v=1.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to make it as close to perfect as possible so constructive criticism would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's a good idea to keep your JavaScript files at the end of your page, before your closing `</body>` tag, so that they don't block your page rendering on load.

Although if you want to improve your sites performance it's good to

- inline short JavaScript
- inline short css
- inline css, that's used to format your page in general (like fixed headers, sidebars, etc.) and add the details like hovers, gradients, box shadows or other awesome css3 stuff in an external stylesheet

At last I have learned to load everything asynchroniously.

I am interested in other answers as well! Good question ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a some formal way to layout.I prefer this way in most of my web designs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  
 <title>Your Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0" media="all">
</head>

<body>

 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>menu itms</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <section>
 
  <article>
   <header>
    <h2>Article title</h2>
    <p>some meta content</p>
   </header>
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </article>
  
  
 </section>

 <aside>
  <h2>section</h2>
  <p>some content</p>
 </aside>

 <footer>
  <p>Copyright notes and some special links</p>
 </footer>
<script src="js/script.js?v=1.0"></script>
</body>

</html>
```